# Unity unlock camera movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, scroll, camera, mouse, mousewheel

I found and edited a java script that moves the camera from pointA -> pointB and back when you use the scroll wheel. But when I make it a child of the player, the camera doesn't move with it. Any ideas why?

This script is used by the camera:

```
var pointB : Vector3;

function Start () {
var pointA = transform.position;
    while (true) {
            yield MoveObject(transform, pointA, pointB, 3.0);
            yield MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointA, 3.0);
        }
}

function MoveObject (thisTransform : Transform, startPos : Vector3, endPos : Vector3, t) {
    var i = 0.0;
    var rate = 0.1;
    while (i < 1.0) {
        i += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * rate;
        thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
        yield;
        i = Mathf.Clamp(i, 0.0, 10.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "not moving with" do you mean that when you move the character, the camera doesn't follow? Or do you mean that this script above stops working when the camera is a child of the character?

Comment: When I move the character, the camera doesn't follow.

Comment: alright then I do not think that is caused by the above script. Can you post a picture of the hierarchy of the character that includes the camera and can you also post the character movement script?

Comment: ![Image](http://s24.postimg.org/jqqvjisu9/hello.jpg).
![Player movement script](http://pastebin.com/WMLVLD1e)

Comment: Is pointB the transform of human parent in your hierarchy or not ?